# What file names are not allowed in OneDrive?

Tags: onedrive, filenames

I have been having some trouble lately with OneDrive files not syncing properly, and each time it turns out to be some obscure naming restriction.

Is there a full list somewhere of what filenames are not allowed in OneDrive?

Comment: Nice self answer. I'd be tempted to try find a title that's going to get more hits from Google, for future searchers. Maybe 'illegal or invalid file names' or something along those lines.

Comment: @Tetsujin Edited with one attempt; feel free to suggest something else here if you can improve on it.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has an article on the topic [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Invalid-file-names-and-file-types-in-OneDrive-OneDrive-for-Business-and-SharePoint-64883a5d-228e-48f5-b3d2-eb39e07630fa).  Some highlights:

- `" * : < > ? / \ |` characters are not allowed.  For some older versions, `~ # % & { }.` are also not allowed.  (The period in that latter list seems a little alarming!)  Less citeable support channels report that dollar signs `$` should also be avoided in file names.
- `_vti_` cannot appear anywhere in a file name
- `forms` isn't supported as a file name when the folder is at the root level for a library, and sometimes when it is not at the root level for a library.  (How was that supposed to be obvious?)
- You can’t create a folder name in SharePoint Online that begins with a tilde (`~`) or have any filename starting with `~$`.
- The following names are prohibited:
  `.lock`, `CON`, `PRN`, `AUX`, `NUL`, `COM1` - `COM9`, `LPT1` - `LPT9`, `desktop.ini`.
- Active Outlook .PST files should NOT be synced in OneDrive.
- Symbolic links, junction points, authenticated proxies, and network/mapped drives are not allowed.
- OneNote notebooks initially created outside of OneDrive cannot be moved into OneDrive.

Comment: Does it allow Unicode above U+FFFF (e.g. emojis)? Dropbox still doesn't.

Comment: @grawity I doubt it, and to avoid further complications, will not try.  Usability and coverage of unusual characters did not appear to have been considered in the design & programming of this software.

Comment: I had a strange problem: non-ASCII filenames *could be downloaded individually*, but **could not be downloaded in bulk**.  There was a strange bug where the filename would be corrupted **in the zipping process**.  This is not a limitation of `zip` itself, which I verified can zip non-ASCII files without a problem.  But I obviously cannot validate what OneDrive is actually doing, except to note that it fails. :(

Answer (score 2):

Forms appears to be one of the "illegal" words.  I renamed it to Forms 2 and everything would sync.  Rename it back to Forms and red Xs everywhere.  I'm also looking for this magical list that will tell us what words aren't allowed.  Why would forms not be a valid name?

Comment: "Why would forms not be a valid name?" Because, unfortunately, the program managers who specified SharePoint behavior are idiots who think that a "few" customers inconvenienced due to an inexplicable and unexpected error is a reasonable price to pay to keep MSFT developers from having to do "extra" work to implement the product properly.

Comment: Filename of "forms" without an extension does not work. It complains that "is already in use".

Answer (score 1):

Just to add that according to this [MSDN source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN), the names:

```
CON, PRN, AUX, NUL, COM1 - COM9, LPT1 - LPT9
```

**followed by any extension** are also not allowed:

> "Also avoid these names followed immediately by an extension;"

ie. aux.c, aux.py, com.anything, ... cannot be uploaded to onedrive.
With some clients, such as [this](https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive), files with these filenames will be uploaded with a different name:

```
~tmpXX<original file name>
```

where XX is an hexadecimal number.
For each sync attempt a new file will be added.
Say for aux.c, after some sync attempts, it will be found on the corresponding remote Onedrive folder, some files with names like:

```
~tmp0Caux.c
~tmp1Caux.c
~tmp4Baux.c
```